# Accessing and manipulating HTML input using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm an new amateur programmer that is having trouble using HTML and JavaScript together. We were tasked to make a simple program that asks us what's the maximum number, I made the logic but still having trouble with this case.

Currently this is the progress with my code

```js
var num1;
var num2;
var num3;
var max;

if (num1 < num2) {
  if (num2 < num3) {
    num3 = max;
  } else if (num2 > num3) {
    num2 = max;
  }
} else if (num1 > num2) {
  if (num1 > num3) {
    num1 = max;
  } else if (num1 < num2) {
    num2 = max;
  }
}

alert("The maximum number is: " + max);
```

```html
<h1>Laboratory 06</h1>
<p>2. Write a JavaScript program to determine the maximum number using 3 input box.</p>
<blockquote>
  <label for=num1>First number:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="a" name=num1><br><br>

  <label for=num2>Second number:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="b" name=num2><br><br>

  <label for=num3>Third number:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="c" name=num3><br><br>

  <button type="button">Enter</button>
</blockquote>
```

Comment: "*still having trouble with this case*" isn't a very specific problem statement. Can you elaborate on what *exactly* it is you're "*still having trouble with*"? Edit your question to include any and all pertinent information (expected vs. actual behavior, error messages, etc.) and to better conform to the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guidelines.

Comment: What does "having trouble" mean? Please state your problem and question more clearly.

Comment: The varaibles have no relationship to the inputs. You need to use event listeners.

Comment: Feel free to ask if anything remains unclear. Don't be shy because you're  a beginner.

Comment: Let me know if everything is understandable.

Comment: Thank you so much sir connexo for the solution and for understanding that I'm a beginner in this field. I think I get the gist of your solution and saw my mistakes because I kinda treated this as a basic C program that's why I got into a lot of errors.

In my end, the output is not showing on the console, I figured that I didn't put the right location of the script, should I put it in the <head> tag , in the <body> tag, or outside the <body> tag?

Comment: update: I got it now.. it must be inside the <body> tag. Originally it was there, though I just kept moving it thinking maybe that was the reason that the output wasn't showing on the console. well anyways, thank you again for the help sir connexo, I'm still figuring out html and javascript from here, C is my mother tongue in programming so I'm adjusting in my new environment.

Comment: @Liam08 Yes, you have several options for making sure the DOM elements are available for accessing via Javascript. One is wrapping your code in a `DOMContentLoaded` event listener. A second is placing your `script` tag right before the closing `</body>` tag (most commonly used). A third one is putting your `script` in the `head` and adding the `defer` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem with your code is that it runs straight away, long before a user has entered any number. The next problem with it is that you never read the values from the inputs.

What you instead want is for the code to **wait until an event occurs** - which, in your case is the event, that **the user clicks the <kbd>Enter</kbd> button**.

For reacting to user actions (and more), Javascript has the concept of `eventListener`s, which you can add to any element. There is many different types of events; the one you care about here is the `click` event.

To add it to the button, you first need your Javascript to learn where your `button` element is. To find it in the page, Javascript offers the `document.querySelector()` method.

Once you have found it, you can call the `addEventListener()` method on the element (all HTML elements have this method built-in).

For an explanation of the rest, check the source code comments (lines that begin with `//`):

```js
// first we need to find the button in the page,
// so we can access it in our Javascript
// the following finds the first <button> element in the page.
const button = document.querySelector('button');

// every HTML element has a addEventListener method
// that takes two arguments:
// the first is the name of the event you want to listen to (String),
// the second is a function that will be executed every time 
// the event occurs.
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // when the user clicks the button, we read what is in the inputs.
  // to do that, we first need our JS to find the inputs.
  // in this case this is especially easy because each of them has a
  // unique identifier (id), so we can use 
  //    document.getElementById(id) 
  // to find it.
  // Once found, we immediately read the value from the input.
  let aValue = document.getElementById('a').value;
  let bValue = document.getElementById('b').value;
  let cValue = document.getElementById('c').value;
  // because the value of any input element is always a String,
  // we now convert it to a Number.
  aValue = parseFloat(aValue);
  bValue = parseFloat(bValue);
  cValue = parseFloat(cValue);
  
  // now we use another built-in object, Math, and on it, the
  // Math.max function, to find the largest number.
  const maxValue = Math.max(aValue, bValue, cValue);

  // to output the maxValue, we use console.log rather than
  // alert. To see the output in the browser, open the browser's
  // developer tools (F12 on Windows), and click the "Console" tab.
  // To make sure not to output anything if no number was entered
  // before the button was clicked, we check if maxValue is a proper
  // number. Javascript has the NaN datatype (Not a Number), 
  // and you can check for it using isNaN(variable)
  if (!isNaN(maxValue)) { // if maxValue is not "Not a number"
    console.log("The maximum number is: " + maxValue);
  }
})
```

```html
<h1>Laboratory 06</h1>
<p>2. Write a JavaScript program to determine the maximum number using 3 input box.</p>
<blockquote>
  <label for=num1>First number:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="a" name=num1><br><br>

  <label for=num2>Second number:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="b" name=num2><br><br>

  <label for=num3>Third number:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="c" name=num3><br><br>

  <button type="button">Enter</button>
</blockquote>
```